# onKeyPreIme does not call

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, keypress, android-event

I have a custom view that inherites `LinearLayout` and that view is in a `ViewSwitcher`. I want to return to previous view on Back pressed, So i overriden the `onPreKeyIme` in this view but when i press Back, it doesnt seem to enter the method, and the activity handles the Back.

What am I missing?

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        return viewModel.backClicked();
    return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event);
}
```

I have a breakpoint in the if-statement and it never freezes there.

PS, I'm not allowed to use fragments.

Comment: why don't you use `onBackPressed` callback instead of `onKeyPreIme`?

Comment: @VasylGlodan I need to capture it in view level.

Comment: Aha, I see. Didn't you think to create some public method in your custom View which will change your view structure/appearance/etc. and call this method outside this view in onBackPressed? Something like:

`public void onBackPressed() {
view.handleBack();
}`

Comment: If there wont be an other way. 
This is a huge and unique project and i'm just handling a small part of it.

Comment: @VasylGlodan, it seams, this code was already implemented. :)

Comment: @SnapDragonI have the same problem. Have you found the solution?

Comment: @JayVDiyk, The solution was that the client added a method in main `Activity` (beyond the scope of my task) that captured the event and called all registered interfaces.

Answer (score 5):

Try overriding the `dispatchKeyEvent` method. Do something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
       Log.d("Test","Back Pressed");
       return viewModel.backClicked();
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: I use 'dispatchKeyEventPreIme'. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Will reward bounty in a day.

Comment: Thanks. Glad I could help you out :)